# Dispatch for useContext not being called in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an app based on https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db-control-center/ which works as intended but when I ported it to my application there are some issues.

Within a useEffect I am calling dispatch which is not changing the application's state. The dispatches are within async functions which are being called and behave as intended but the dispatches aren't updating the UI. I am using parcel to help hot-reload during dev. On page load the dispatches aren't being called but when the page is updated (not-refreshed) using parcel hot-reload the dispatches work as intended.

Systems.js

```
  const [appState, dispatch] = useStateValue()
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAMS_LOADING, loading: true })

    initIPFS().then(async (ipfs) => {
      dispatch({ type: actions.SYSTEMS.SET_IPFS, ipfsStatus: 'Started' })

      initOrbitDB(ipfs).then(async () => {
        dispatch({ type: actions.SYSTEMS.SET_ORBITDB, orbitdbStatus: 'Started' })
        const programs = await getAllDatabases(pid)
        dispatch({ type: actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAMS, programs: programs.reverse() })
        dispatch({ type: actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAMS_LOADING, loading: false })
      })
    })
  }, [dispatch])
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Outlet} from 'react-router-dom'

import { actions, loadingState, 
  StateProvider 
} from './state'

import {Systems} from './components/Systems'
import {Header} from './components/Header'

import './index.css'


export function DBView () {
  const initialState = {
    user: null,
    loginDialogOpen: false,
    createDBDialogOpen: false,
    addDBDialogOpen: false,
    programs: [],
    program: false,
    db: null,
    entries: [],
    orbitdbStatus: 'Starting',
    ipfsStatus: 'Starting',
    loading: {
      programs: false
    }
  }

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch (action.type) {
      case actions.SYSTEMS.SET_ORBITDB:
        return {
          ...state,
          orbitdbStatus: action.orbitdbStatus
        }
      case actions.SYSTEMS.SET_IPFS:
        return {
          ...state,
          ipfsStatus: action.ipfsStatus
        }
      case actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAM:
        return {
          ...state,
          program: action.program
        }
      case actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAM_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          program: loadingState
        }
      case actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAMS:
        return {
          ...state,
          programs: action.programs
        }
      case actions.DB.SET_DB:
        return {
          ...state,
          db: action.db,
          entries: action.entries,
        }
      case actions.DB.OPEN_CREATEDB_DIALOG:
        return {
          ...state,
          createDBDialogOpen: true
        }
      case actions.DB.CLOSE_CREATEDB_DIALOG:
        return {
          ...state,
          createDBDialogOpen: false
        }
      case actions.DB.OPEN_ADDDB_DIALOG:
        return {
          ...state,
          addDBDialogOpen: true
        }
      case actions.DB.CLOSE_ADDDB_DIALOG:
        return {
          ...state,
          addDBDialogOpen: false
        }
      case actions.PROGRAMS.SET_PROGRAMS_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: { ...state.loading, programs: action.loading }
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  return (
      <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
        <Header />
        <Systems />
        <Outlet />
      </StateProvider>
  )
}
```

state/index.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react'

export const StateContext = createContext()

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
)

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)

export const actions = {
  DB: {
    OPEN_CREATEDB_DIALOG: 'OPEN_CREATEDB_DIALOG',
    CLOSE_CREATEDB_DIALOG: 'CLOSE_CREATEDB_DIALOG',
    OPEN_ADDDB_DIALOG: 'OPEN_ADDDB_DIALOG',
    CLOSE_ADDDB_DIALOG: 'CLOSE_ADDDB_DIALOG',
    SET_DB: 'SET_DB'
  },
  SYSTEMS: {
    SET_IPFS: 'SET_IPFS',
    SET_ORBITDB: 'SET_ORBITDB'
  },
  PROGRAMS: {
    SET_PROGRAMS: 'SET_PROGRAMS',
    SET_PROGRAMS_LOADING: 'SET_PROGRAMS_LOADING',
    SET_PROGRAM: 'SET_PROGRAM',
    SET_PROGRAM_LOADING: 'SET_PROGRAM_LOADING'
  }
}

export const loadingState = 'loading'
```

Comment: Where are you getting `useStateValue` from? It's not standard a React hook, and it's not Redux or Recoil...

Comment: @Andy I am getting it from state/index.js it is line 11 in the third code block